# Virtualenv doesn't fail despite no installed packages

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, python-venv, requirements.txt

I have a new laptop and on cloning down my python projects I was wanting to formalise them by including a requirements.txt file and to start using venvs.

When running the python file normally as expected it complains about missing packages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 1, in <module>
  from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
ImportError: No module named request
```

This is the first error and there are many others which I would expect to error.

However when I create a venv and run the same code there is no error and the scripts produces the expected output, how is this working? My only guess is that vscode has started doing something behind the scenes when using a venv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, with a virtual environment, many python3 packages are 'reset'. A virtual environment is more python3 compatible: it contains more python3 built-in packages and is completely different from your home python thingy. Also, `python` would invoke the python3 in a virtualenv

Comment: Thanks @theX
Is it wise to still include these packages in a requirements file for interoperability with users who may not be on python 3?

Comment: @Andrew Python2 is deprecated so, personally, I would expect people to use python3. **I can't really judge if it's wise or not to do so, though.** Use your discretion.